# ReactJS production build css replaces 0px with 0 inside clamp function

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using CSS clamp in grid-template-columns. In one of the clamp function I am giving 0px as minimum value. When I am running the application in local dev server, the 0px is coming as it is. But when I go to production build, the 0px in the clamp function is getting replaced by just 0, which is breaking the UI.

**Dev minified CSS**

`grid-template-columns: clamp(10.31rem, 25%, 25%) clamp(9.68rem, 15%, 15%) clamp(6.56rem, 20%, 20%) clamp(9.06rem, 12.5%, 12.5%) clamp(9.68rem, 12.5%, 12.5%) clamp(5.93rem, 8%, 8%) clamp(0px, 3%, 3%);`

**Prod minified CSS**

`grid-template-columns: clamp(10.31rem, 25%, 25%) clamp(9.68rem, 15%, 15%) clamp(6.56rem, 20%, 20%) clamp(9.06rem, 12.5%, 12.5%) clamp(9.68rem, 12.5%, 12.5%) clamp(5.93rem, 8%, 8%) clamp(0, 3%, 3%);`

The **0px** in the last clamp function is replaced just with a **0**. I really don't know how to bypass this issue. Can someone help me with this?

I am using react version **16.9.36**

Comment: How do you build your project? Is this vanilla Create React App?

Comment: Yes @ezhikov. It's the create-react-app build, which uses the react-scripts

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do much with default CRA without ejecting. There are projects to configure CRA without ejecting, like [CRACO](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco), but you should also submit an issue to Create React App. Actual bug is, most possibly somewhere in dependencies of OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin (direct or indirect).

Comment: okay thanks @ezhikov.

As of now, to bypass the issue I have passed 1px instead of 0px.

Comment: This is a very frustrating problem. It would be nice if the CRA team could have a look or make a comment about it. Ejecting to solve this one is like using a nuclear bomb to kill an ant.